# Why does same percentage of house edge earn the game less/more money?

Tags: probability

Let's say I have a game (1000 slots roulette) with 60 slots that you can win with. 
So the probability of winning is 0.06;

Now to attract players, I have a discount system. That is if discount is 30%, you pay 1 dollar to play, you only need to pay 0.7 dollars. But if you win the payout is 10 dollars.

**GAME A**

So the expected house edge on $1 should be

(1-D) - 60 / 1000 * P = (1 - 0.3) - 60 / 1000 * 10 = 0.1

**GAME B**

I can modify the game to maintain the same house edge, with different discount and payout

D = 0.24, P = 11

(1-D) - 60 / 1000 * P = (1 - 0.24) - 60 / 1000 * 11 = 0.1

So from player point of view both games are the same (probability wise). But if a player can choose he probably will choose to play **Game B**.

**Why?**

Player 1 play Game A for 1320, after discount:  924, potential winning:  13200,

Player 2 play Game B for 1200, after discount:  912, potential winning:  13200,

As you can see player  2 is better off, same potential winning, but he pays lesser!

I cannot figure out what causes this inconsistency when the house edge is obviously the same, it seems one game earn more money than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in calculating the edge of the house. In the first case, the house is expected to make \$0.1 for every \$0.7 bet, or approximately 14.2% of the initial bet. In the second case, the house is expected to make \$0.1 for every \$0.76 bet, or approximately 13.2% of the initial bet. Indeed, from the gambler's perspective, the second scenario is the most interesting.

Note that you can take this a few steps further, by considering no discount and a payout of \$15. In this case, the edge of the house is \$0.1 for every \$1 bet, or 10% of the initial bet. From the gambler's perspective, this solution is the best approach.

Comment: Thank you. I see my mistake now, so do the house edge formula above mean anything at all?

Comment: @Zanko They certainly do: they determine the expected profit given an initial bet. As stated above, both the \$0.7 and \$0.76 bet respectively result in a profit of $0.1.

Comment: Hi, sorry but something still doesn't add up for me. $0.1 for every $0.7 bet, or approximately 14.2% vs $0.1 for every $0.76 bet, or approximately 13.2%. Obviously house has better edge for the first case. But looking at expected profit given an initial bet both are $0.1. So both games are actually the same?

Comment: @Zanko No, the expected profit is not the same. In the first case, the house wins $\frac{1}{7}$ of the amount bet, in the second case $\frac{1}{7.6}$ of the amount bet. Say a gambler bets \$532 in both scenarios, then the house is expected to win \$76 in the first scenario, and \$70 in the second.

Comment: Thank you I understand that. I guess I just can't figure out what `(1-D) - 60 / 1000 * P = (1 - 0.3) - 60 / 1000 * 10 = 0.1` and `(1-D) - 60 / 1000 * P = (1 - 0.24) - 60 / 1000 * 11 = 0.1` meant. They both give value of 0.1. It is expected profit GIVEN initial bet. But this information is useless to casino right?

Comment: @Zanko It is the expected profit per \$0.7 and \$0.76 bet, respectively. This information is crucial to determine the ratio of profit, given an initial bet. The problem is that you're using two different values as the initial bet, and falsely come to the conclusion that the expected relative profit is the same, while this is only true for the expected absolute profit (\$0.1). To overcome this, simply plug in $1 as the initial bet in both scenarios. You will find an expected gain of \$0.142 in the first scenario, and \$0.132 in the second.

Comment: @I see it now! Thank you. One more question, if the player enter the game with 100 Cash (before discount) will I be expected to make (14.2% of 100) or (14.2% of (100 * discount))?

Comment: @Zanko You are expected to earn 14.2% of \$100, or \$14.2.